# SpriteKit - Error while creating a button

Tags: ios, button, sprite-kit

here is my custom button class:

```
import SpriteKit

class Button: SKNode {

    var defaultButton: SKSpriteNode
    var activeButton: SKSpriteNode
    var action: () -> Void

    init(defaultImage: String, activeImage: String, buttonAction: () -> Void) {

        defaultButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: defaultImage)
        activeButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: activeImage)
        action = buttonAction

        activeButton.hidden = true

        super.init()

        userInteractionEnabled = true

        addChild(defaultButton)
        addChild(activeButton)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            activeButton.hidden = false
            defaultButton.hidden = true


        }

    }


    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if defaultButton.containsPoint(location) {
                action()
            }

            activeButton.hidden = true
            defaultButton.hidden = false
        }
    }
```

Here is how I'm initializing it in `GameScene`:

```
  var button = Button(defaultImage: "default_Image", activeImage: "active_Image", buttonAction: someFunction)
  button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)

    addChild(Button) // <- Error here !
```

The error I get: "Cannot convert value of type '(Button).Type' (aka 'Button.Type') to expected argument type 'SKNode'"

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You want `addChild(button)`, not `addChild(Button)`. Case matters in Swift.

Comment: This might be  the silliest mistake I have ever done in programming :/ Also no need for downvoting.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question. It won't be useful to anyone else (hence the down vote).